# C++ Primer 5th Edition, Exercise 1.23 no output

Tags: c++

I am teaching myself C++ with the C++ primer and have been stumped for two days on exercise 1.23. Here is the problem:

> Exercises Section 1.5.2
>
> Exercise 1.23: Write a program that reads several transactions and counts how many transactions occur for each ISBN.
>
> Exercise 1.24: Test the previous program by giving multiple transactions 
>   representing multiple ISBNs. The records for each ISBN should be grouped together.

I am supposed to provide this using a class called "Sales_item" that takes input of an ISBN, number of items, and sale price (such as `<ISBN> 4 24.99`). It also enables the following operations:

I have tried to do the first exercise with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main()
{
  int cnt = 0;
  Sales_item item1, item2, item3, item4;
  //Verify we have data from the infile
  if (std::cin >> item1) {
    cnt = 1;
    //read the rest of the transactions and add to cnt for each
    while (std::cin >> item2 >> item3 >> item4) {
      cnt++;
    }
  }
  else {
    std::cout << item1.isbn() << " has a total of " << cnt <<
    " transactions." << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My thinking is that the while loop should increment the cnt variable each time a transaction is passed to the standard input and then output a statement reflecting the number of transactions when it reaches the end of the list, but I am not getting anything for the output. Is my reasoning/logic wrong on how this should work?

Comment: The only way out of the input loop is to close stdin. You should be able to do this with ctrl+D or CTRL+Z depending on the operating system. Note: once you close stdin it is hard to get std::cin to work again.

Answer (score 1):

The [operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) of iostreams like `cin` returns the stream itself, that's how you can chain them.  So the test inside your while loop is always non-zero, and therefore never exits.